# High Power Consumption and Wakeups on my Asus X54H

Tags: 12.04, battery, asus

So I've been using powertop to try and reduce the power consumption on my laptop as I only seem to get about 3 hours of battery. From reading other threads on here it seems my power consumption and wakeups are strangely high, here's a summary:

The battery reports a discharge rate of 10.2 W

```
Summary: 651.8 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/second and 0.0 VFS ops/sec
```

The things which stand out as odd:

```
1.31 W      4.0 ms/s     166.7        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard / Mouse
```

So more than 10% of my battery is being consumed by my touchpad/keyboard? That doesn't seem right.

```
548 mW     34.3 ms/s      45.9        Process        compiz
```

5% from Compiz. Is this correct?

```
376 mW      1.8 ms/s      47.5        Interrupt      [51] i915
298 mW      1.4 ms/s      37.7        Timer          tick_sched_timer
```

Another few percent from these things- not quite sure what they are.

For reference I've installed Laptop Mode Tools, Jupiter (on power save), the CPU governor is definitely on powersave and brightness is on minimum.

What else can I do/Any ideas? I've seen other posts on here reporting laptop battery lives of ~8 hours and power consumption of 4W rather than my 10W...

Comment: Did you install proprietary drivers?  Several of the default drivers (including for graphics and wireless) do not have *any* power management at all.  You can probably shave several watts off from just that.

Also, as I found out once I installed new drivers... powertop can be incredibly misleading.  It detects all kinds of stuff.  Right now my battery is draining 7W on average, but powertop insists my keyboard/trackpad is using up a steady 12.5W.  How does that work, I wonder.

Comment: i915 is your Intel graphics chip.

Comment: No proprietary drivers showed up in the additional drivers thing. I haven't investigated if there any any ones available for download on the intel site, will check when I get home. Thanks for the idea! I did check for proprietary drivers for wireless, there are none.

Answer (score 0):

**12.04 is still in Beta**. Just today I received 120 updates so that means that 12.04 is not for production/working environment yet (Although it might look stable enough). So you will have to wait for the final release of 12.04 to test your problem again. For me, I also installed Jupiter and that is when all battery problems started. I had to removed the battery and wait about 15 minutes. Then connected the battery again and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend consulting:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues

and also:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks